# Windows Azure Sql Database Management Portal Error

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I ve done some research and i can't seem to find anything similar to this.

I have an SQL Database from Windows Azure with several tables. I can log in just fine and view all the table data of all tables, except from a specific table.

When I click on the "Data" section of that specific table, my screen just goes completely blank and then I can't do nothing about it, apart from starting over. Any thoughts on this ?
(I have the latest version of Silverlight installed and I ve tried with Chrome,Firefox and Opera)

Thanks

Comment: One of the reasons why that can happen is that this particular table has lots of information in it (lots of columns or large values) and it takes lots of time to load the data. Try to get data from that table again but this time and leave your browser open for much longer say, couple of hours, and see if that helps.

Comment: I would not say that cause the overall free space of this database is 99% . The size of that table was ~100Kb. I deleted though half of the entries and left my browser open for a while and still,I have the same problem

Comment: And do you get the same issue when trying to connect to your database with SQL Server Management Studio (see answer by Sampath)?

Comment: No issue is solved. Thanks for your response!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use **SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2008 R2** for browse or what ever the task you have to do with SQL azure database as a alternative for your way of method.

Using SQL Server Management Studio 2008 R2 to Manage SQL Azure sample screen is as below.

[image]

For more information check this out [**Getting Started with SQL Azure Development**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/gg309175.aspx)

**UPDATE**

If you're going to use express edition, then you have to use SQL 2012 express with Win 8.

Check this out [**SQL Express Edition 2012**](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/sqlserver/editions/2012-editions/express.aspx)

I hope this will help to you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It seems that this software has compatibility issues with Windows8 when i tried to install it

Comment: @Andreas which software having compatibility issues ?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) 2008 R2 . On installation. I dont know if there are any specific configurations needed to be made for Windows 8? Cause it says that is not supported

Comment: @Andreas Plz check "Update" section of my post.

Comment: I am on it now. Thanks for your answer